# Create multiple subsets of a time series based on Period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing a time series such as follow:

[image]

I would like to create multiple subsets of that DataFrame, that would each contain on week worth of data, spanning from Sunday 0am to Saturday 0am.

I can think of a way to do that with RRule from timeutil, but it seems there might be a more intuitive/direct method using Pandas Periods.

However I am quite new to it so not sure where to start looking. Ideally it would be something like:

```
Period= Sun 0am to Sat 0am
Subsets=[]
for Period in DataFrame:
    Subsets.append(DataFrame[Period])
```

Something like that.....

data:

```
Pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=['timestamp','open','high','low','close','volume'])

dict={'volume': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 521.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 234.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 164.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 99.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 1603.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 389.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 590.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 1668.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 79.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 213.0}, 'low': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 1225.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 1225.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 1226.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 1225.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 1226.75}, 'timestamp': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 732011.79166666663, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 732011.83333333337, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 732011.85416666663, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 732011.875, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 732011.72916666663, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 732011.89583333337, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 732011.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 732011.70833333337, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 732011.8125, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 732011.77083333337}, 'open': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 1227.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 1226.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 1225.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 1225.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 1227.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 1225.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 1227.25}, 'high': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 1227.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 1226.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 1226.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 1227.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 1227.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 1226.75, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 1227.5}, 'close': {Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:00:00'): 1226.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 20:30:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:00:00'): 1226.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'): 1227.0, Timestamp('2005-03-06 21:30:00'): 1225.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'): 1227.25, Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'): 1225.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 19:30:00'): 1226.5, Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:30:00'): 1226.75}}
```

Comment: can you please psot real data instead of images

Comment: @e4c5 I pasted few rows. I tried to paste a couple of weeks worth of data but obviously its too much. Maybe by using a smaller period its possible to test though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#sample dataframe
start = pd.to_datetime('2016-12-28')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=100, freq='100min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': rng, 'X': range(100), 
                   'id': ['a'] * 30 + ['b'] * 30 + ['c'] * 40 })  
df = df.set_index(['timestamp'])
#print (df)
```

First filter out weekends by [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if necessary:

```
#df = df[df.index.dayofweek < 5]
#print (df)
```

Then use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html) with week frequency:

```
#first date in index
first_date = df.index[0]
#last date in index
last_date = df.index[-1]
per = pd.period_range(first_date,last_date, freq='W')
print (per)
PeriodIndex(['2016-12-26/2017-01-01', 
             '2017-01-02/2017-01-08'], dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN')
```

Last create `Subsets` by `list comprehension` with converting each period [`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) and select values by `loc`:

```
Subsets = [ df.loc[x.to_timestamp('D', how='s'): x.to_timestamp('D', how='e')] for x in per]
#print (Subsets)
```

If `loc` cannot be used, because end-points are not included in `Dataetimeindex` use `boolean indexing`:

```
Subsets = [ df[(df.index > x.to_timestamp('D', how='s')) & 
               (df.index < x.to_timestamp('D', how='e'))] for x in per]
#print (Subsets)
```